# Bloque informacion de usuario por prestashop

Tags: php, linux, prestashop

Buenas tardes. Encontré navegando por internet, que si quiero cambiar los campos de mi bloque de informacionde usuario, debo editar el archivo `nav.tpl` dentro de `prestashop>themes>nombre_tema>modules>blockuserinfo>nav.tpl` ahi (asumo), se debe editar lo que se quiere mostrar en la vista. pero al momento de editar no me toma los cambios. Alguien sabe a que se debe esto?

Comment: @Luiggi, Linux? No puedes crear tags?

Comment: @brasofilo si puedo, pero no sé qué colocar. ¿Prestashop quizás? Si solo son preguntas de un único usuario hasta ahora, no creo que valga la pena. Por otro lado, solo removí la etiqueta Java en el tema.

Comment: @Luiggi, entonces PHP

Comment: @brasofilo la pregunta no hace referencia a programación en PHP en absoluto, por lo que no creo que sería adecuado colocar esa etiqueta. Es como etiquetar con Java a todas las preguntas que refieren sobre Eclipse o NetBeans p.e. *cómo importar proyectos en el IDE*, estos IDEs están hechos con Java pero la pregunta no es de Java.

Comment: all right, es que tampoco entiendo que tiene que ver Linux con esto... por eso pregunte si no podias crear la tag

Comment: @brasofilo la verdad yo tampoco creo que esto deba ver con linux pero no puedo dejar la pregunta sin etiquetas.

Comment: pues crear etiquetas es gratis :p (y mejor que cambiar algo equivocado por otra cosa equivocada)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero, ¿Java? Prestashop esta hecho en PHP. Lo otro, posiblemente es caché, intente borrar toda la caché que Prestashop genera; en muchas ocasiones es solamente ese detalle el que no nos permite ver los cambios hechos.

Lo otro es hacer algún "override" del módulo, específicamente del archivo tpl pero yo me inclino más por lo primero.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Si sirvio.. Pero extrañamente cada vez que hago un cambio tengo que activar y desactivar el cache de prestashop, pero si sirve! Nuevamente gracias
Nota: Coloque java por error, trabajo con java y no me di cuenta de mi error, neuvamente gracias

Comment: @mestanza Si esta respuesta te ayudo, puedes considerar en marcarla como respuesta aceptada, asi ayudas a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema :)

Comment: @mestanza el problema es que Smarty genera caché, por ende por cada cambio toca borrar caché. Cuando se trate de desarrollo es preferible desactivar la caché para luego de todos los ajustes dejar la caché activa en producción.